# Turn loop in to arrow function Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, arrow-functions

I have a simple loop I want to turn into an arrow function

The function deletes all rows from the mainArray when there is a match in columns B or C with data in searchArray

removeROW_LOOP() works but removeROW_ARROW() does not

I get the error when running removeROW_ARROW() `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 14 but the range has 21.`

Thanks for any assistance with this

My data looks like
mainArray
[image]

searchArray

[image]

results

[image]

Loop (works)

```
function removeROW_LOOP() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const searchArray = ss.getSheetByName('Helper_(ignore)').getDataRange().getDisplayValues().flat();
  const mainArray = ss.getSheetByName('Connections').getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 
  let result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= searchArray.length-1; i++) {
     result = removeROW(mainArray, searchArray[i]);
  }

  const sht = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht.clear()  
  sht.getRange(1,1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

My attempt at arrow function (does not work)

```
function removeROW_ARROW() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const searchArray = ss.getSheetByName('Helper_(ignore)').getDataRange().getDisplayValues().flat();
  const mainArray = ss.getSheetByName('Connections').getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 

  const result = searchArray.map(s => removeROW(mainArray, s));

  const sht = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht.clear()  
  sht.getRange(1,1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

and

```
function removeROW(array, item) {
  array = array.filter(a => a[1]!=item && a[2]!=item);
  return array
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is function vs. arrow function. Your refactor actually changes the behavior significantly.

**removeROW_LOOP**() will reset **result** upon each iteration with the newly filtered array. However, in **removeROW_ARROW()**, **result** will be an array of arrays. Specifically, each item in the **result** will be a filtered version of **mainArray** with only one **searchArray** entry filtered out of it.

I think you want somthing along these lines:

```
function removeUPDATED() {
  // ...

  const result = mainArray.filter(x => !searchArray.includes(x[0]) && !searchArray.includes(x[1]));

  // ...
}
```

I might have included a bug there, but I think it demonstrates the approach you want.